# what is included in base grand total magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I need to create a custom getBaseGrandTotal amount. What is included in this amount like a tax, shipping.tax?

I am new to Magento.

Please guide!!!

Comment: discount, shipping, subtotal, tax and etc. Magento total calculation can be customized based on what you need.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: i want to override module paypal Express/Checkout.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your settings but basically:

Subtotal, shipping, shipping tax (if you are using that), tax and discount. 
What do you want to change about the grand total? [Here](https://blog.magestore.com/checkout-totals-in-magento/) is some info on updating the grand total.